# I have product ID.. i need product name and url

Tags: magento-1.7

I have this in my customer dashboard, so people can see and unsubscribe from product alerts:

```
<?PHP
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$customer_price_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/price')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
foreach ( $customer_price_alerts as $alert )
{
 echo $alert->getProductId();
}
    ?>
```

I can put some stuff in the echo to add unsubscribe link and more. The "more" is my problem. I can only echo the product ID... WHen i use echo $alert->getProductName(); or Url... it aint showing me stuff... just empty fields.

Can this be done? Else i need to know how to convert my product ID to a clickable link, so people can click and check what product is behind the ID (ugly... but better than nothing).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$customer_price_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/price')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
foreach ( $customer_price_alerts as $alert )
{
 $productId = $alert->getProductId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $product->getName();
}
```

Try it.

Comment: You are great :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);
$url = $product->getProductUrl();
$name = $product->getName();
```

Comment: i added your lines in my php snipet... i get "www.domain.com/catalog/product/view" when i use $product->getProductUrl() And when i use $product->getName() i get nothing :(   ANd when i use links like this: http://www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/33910/ i get a 404 error page. I use fancy url rewritten links ;)

Answer (score 1):

$productId = $alert->getProductId();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName();

Comment: this just shows errors: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object The error is in this: $productId = $alert->getProductId();